# Hibernate: Many to many deletion deleting entire table

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have a ManyToMany relationship between `Doctor` & `Patient` through a entity `AppointmentRequest`. However, when I delete 1 `Doctor` every `Doctor` & `Patient` associated through the `AppointmentRequest` table is deleted.

Here is my code:

**Doctor**

```
public class Doctor implements Person {

    private List<AppointmentRequest> appointmentRequests = new ArrayList<AppointmentRequest>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="doctor", targetEntity = AppointmentRequest.class, 
             fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL) 
    public List<AppointmentRequest> getAppointmentRequests() {
        return this.appointmentRequests;
    }

}
```

**Patient**

```
public class Patient implements Person {

   private List<AppointmentRequest> appointmentRequests = new ArrayList<AppointmentRequest>();

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="patient", targetEntity = AppointmentRequest.class, 
         fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL) 
   public List<AppointmentRequest> getAppointmentRequests() {
       return this.appointmentRequests;
   }

}
```

**AppointmentRequest**

```
public class AppointmentRequest {

   private Doctor doctor;
   private Patient patient;

   @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL) 
   @JoinColumn(name="doctor_id") 
   public Doctor getDoctor() {
       return doctor;
   }

   @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL) 
   @JoinColumn(name="patient_id") 
   public Patient getPatient() {
       return patient;
   }
}
```

**Doctor delete code**

```
public void deleteDoctor(String doctor_name) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Doctor.findByName");
        query.setString("name", doctor_name);
        doctor = (Doctor) query.uniqueResult();
        if(doctor == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        List<AppointmentRequest> appointments = doctor.getAppointmentRequests();
        for(AppointmentRequest appointment:appointments) {
            appointment.setDoctor(null);
        }
        session.delete(doctor);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have cascade.all set on the collections. This will delete everything that is related. It is like a ripple effect, all the sub children will be deleted if parent is deleted.

Comment: You have got the manytomany mapping wrong. Please look at this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: Why is the many to many mapping wrong. It works perfectly, I actually implemented that solution last night and it does the same exact thing as my solution. Can you please tell me the benefits of that solution vs mine. Also, you are correct, cascade should have not been set to all.

Comment: I actually commented on that article last night. I wanted to know the benefits of using that solution vs this one.

Answer (score 0):

In a `ManyToMany` relation with join table, the existence of join table is only for creating the relation. When a relation is broken/deleted Hibernate
would automatically update/remove the row entry corresponding to that relation in the table. The join table has no equivalent Entity definition. In other words
the row in the join table does not represent Entity in itself. It has no identity and it cannot be shared / referred to by other entities. However in your case the way you have modelled is that
you have created a seperate entity `AppointmentRequest` which is shareable / referenceable and  encapsulates the relationship. This design is usually done when apart from the two related entity you have some other attribute to store for e.g., created date, created by etc. You can then ask the entity to tell when this relation was created or by whom. So the question you need to ask is whether you just want a `many-to-many` relation or your relation is an entity in its own right.

Comment: Yes there is a specific need for my JOIN table to be an entity. I store other attributes in there that I left out in my example code. I thought I should just share the specifics necessary for my problem